# Validating a user on every page using session information, c# & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

My question is more of a request for advice on how to implement a feature to a website using session information. I have a website that asks for username and password on the landing page. When a user successfully logs in, a session is created that stores their username and a few other variables related to the account. In the `Page_Load` function immediately following login, I successfully access this information attached to the user via session variables, verifying that it is implemented properly.

In the MySession class:

```
private MySession()
{
   Username = Data.User.lblUsername;
   CompanyId = Data.User.lblCompanyId;
}
```

In my welcome page (immediately following successful login)

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   secure_username = MySession.Current.Username;
   ...
}
```

I want to use this information, i.e. `secure_username` to validate the user once a page is accessed so that people can no longer skip the login form. From `MySession` class, do I simply use `if(MySession.Current.Username == ??)` statements to check each variable at the start of the `Page_Load` function, or is there a proper way to go about this?

Please ask for clarification if it is needed. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Based on some of the responses given, i think it is important to note that if a user suddenly becomes anonymous (or times out) they should be redirected to the login page.

Comment: If you set form authentication in `web.config` and add proper `authorization` tags in `web.config` you dont have to check if user is authenticated in every page. Did you look into `HttpContext.User`? check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using form authentication then you can add following tags to `web.config` to deny any anonymous access. If you do this, you don't have to check if user is logged in on every page.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```

Add this to allow all users to see Login.aspx so that they can login

```
<location path="Login.aspx" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Add this so that all your css/images folders are visible to anonymous users

```
<location path="css" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="images" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

You may have to add extra location tags based on your website setup and the folders you want any anonymous user to have access to

If login form authentication session expires user will be redirected to url you mention in this tag

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30">
</forms>
```

Comment: Something I need to add to the OP is that any user on a secure webpage that suddenly becomes anonymous needs to be redirected to the landing page. If i implement your suggestions, is that done automatically, or does it just prevent further access?

Comment: yes if login session expires, user is automatically redirected to login url you set in form authentication tag.

Comment: @rs this does not address the question. Session timeout is different from settings related to authorization

Comment: @Ulises, i didn't understand your comment

Comment: @rs I just meant that session timeout (and forms timeout) are separate from authorization settings.

Comment: @Ulises, yes and i didn't mention anywhere that they are related to authorization, i said they are from authentication setting (default 30). check  last few lines from my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do the same action on every page it sounds like you need a base class where all your secure pages inherit from:

**Base page:**

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  public user secure_username
  {get;set;}

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //add your checks that repeat on each page
  }
}
```

**Other pages:**

```
public class AuthenticatedUsersPage : BasePage
{

}
```

**Note**: This of course assumes that you have already taken care of authorization and authentication on your config file (see rs' answer for more info). Also, if you are using forms authentication, remember to make your session last longer than your forms authentication timeout.

Comment: if you are using form authentication and set authorization location tags you don't need separate base class.

Comment: @rs. of course, this is in case you need special checks logic on each page. See my note.